# Why is the resistance in a coaxial cable inversely proportional to the length?

Tags: electromagnetism, electrical-resistance, classical-electrodynamics

I have two coaxial metal cylinders of radii $a$ and $b$, respectively, separated by some conducting material. I have the relevant expression for the resistance between the two cylinders; however, it has come out that the resistance is inversely proportional to the length of the cylinders:

$$R=\frac{\ln(\frac{b}{a})}{2\pi\sigma l}$$

Why is this the case? The resistance should be directly proportional to the length, right? Why does it change in this example?

Answer (score 3):

Expanding on Pieter's answer, consider a transmission line (coaxial cable) lumped model that includes resistance, capacitance, inductance, and conductance.  You can easily google this model to find detailed descriptions.   However, below I show a simple diagram of the lumped model:

[image]

The salient feature of the model is that resistance (R) and inductance (L) are proportional to length where as capacitance (C) and conductance (G) are between the two conductors (two cylinders).  Thus, what you call resistance in your question is known as conductance (or, the inverse of resistance) in the lumped model.

Pieter is correct in that this "pathway" is perpendicular to the length but it is not what most engineers (as opposed to physicists) would refer to as the resistance but rather call it the conductance (inverse resistance) to make the distinction.

Answer (score 1):

Because these resistance pathways are in parallel (perpendicular to the axis of the cylinder).

Comment: What do you mean by resistance "pathways?"

Comment: @AustereTiger The current is not along the length of your cylinder but perpendicular to it. So when the cylinder is twice as long, you will have half the resistance (as if there were two resistances in parallel). Make a drawing.

Comment: So the resistance is inversely proportional because the current flows perpendicularly to the axis of the cylinder?

Comment: It would be good if you provide a bit more elaborated answer.

Comment: @JohanLiebert What is wrong with concise answers?

Comment: Actually I don't have any problem with your answer. But I saw this post flagged as low quality in review queue so just thought to tell you :-)

Comment: @JohanLiebert I wrote this first as a comment. Then I remembered that one should not answer questions in comments. It was a fast answer, and easy to understand. And correct.

Comment: As far as my experience goes, I have found that users here tend to not like one-liners (though I don't have any problem with them as long as they provide all the neccessary details), but currently I am not in a situation to judge your post so can't tell much. But the other problem is that mods too don't like one-liners in comments. So double trouble. :-)